# Tensors and Equalizers (or Symmetric tensors)

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

Quick question: Let $(\text{Sym}(V^{\otimes n}), e)$ be the equalizer of all the $S_n$ braidings (that is for $\sigma \in S_n$ we have $a_1\otimes\cdots\otimes a_n \mapsto a_{\sigma 1} \otimes \cdots\otimes a_{\sigma n}$) on $V^{\otimes n}$.

Is $(x \otimes \text{Sym}(V^{\otimes n}), \text{id}_x\otimes e)$ the equalizer of the $(\text{id}_x\otimes  \sigma)_{\sigma\in S_n}$ in $\mathbf{Ab}$? Can this be generalised for general $EM(T)$ for $T$ a Set monad and construction of the tensor product *à la* Kock[1]?

[1] A. Kock. Bilinearity and Cartesian closed monads.

Comment: What is $V$? Do you work in a closed symmetric monoidal category? Does $\textbf{Ab}$ denote the category of abelian groups? Why should tensoring with some object preserve equalizers?

Comment: 1) $V$ is any object of the category, in the first question $V$ is an abelian group in the second a $T$-algebra. 2) Yes. 3) Not every, equalizer just this one.